# Which way is legitimate to store &process big amounts of data in database? Store all in one table or create new table by id (property)for each?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database, database-design

I am planing to design a database which may have to store huge amounts of data. But i am not sure which way i should use for this? the records may have fields like user id, record date, group, coordinate and perhaps other properties like that, but the key is the user id. 
then i may have to call (select) or process the records with that user id. there may be thousands of user ids so here is the question.

> 1-) on every record; i should directly store all records in a single table? and
>   then call or process them like "... WHERE userId=12345 ...".
>
> 2-) on every record; i should check if there exists a table with that
>   user id and if not create a new table with the user id as table name
>   and store its data in that table. and then call or process them with
>   "SELECT * FROM  ...".

So what would you suggest me?

Comment: Create a single Users table for user records, not a table for every user, otherwise you might as well simply use filesystem files.... let the database do what a database is good at doing

Comment: @suspectus, i am sorry about not being able to give you precise values :(. but I am not sure about how much it can grow. my estimate would be (it may differ) about 30 to 100billion records in 3months. may be not precise but at least something :(.

Comment: i agree with you @MarkBaker but i guess that changes if you have large (huge) amounts of data. i think it will take a lot of time for the sql to select only the values for the specified user and return them to you. because that i am not so sure.

Comment: It doesn't change if you have large amounts of data (even if you're talking thousands of millions of users), if your table is indexed on userId (as most people would do)... If the database can use that index to search, then it doesn't matter how many millions of user records you have

Comment: @SteveMartin, actually i didn't think to use option2 too. but this values have the chance to grow really big. it has an open end. that is why i am hesitating. otherwise i wouldn't think to use option2.

Comment: You'll run into a lot of other problems if you have 100 billion user records (is this an official census of the world population for the year 3000?, current world population is around the 7.2 billion mark) such as scalability of your database, and might need to introduce techniques such as sharding

Comment: no @MarkBaker, it isn't about a census :). it will be a database that will store gps coordinates of users. they will give these records every 2 seconds. and i want to design this system to be able to have 20000 users. so do you think that for example mysql could handle this?

Comment: yes in fact @MarkBaker that was the reason for thinking about 2OPTION.

Comment: Properly indexed, MySQL is perfectly capable of handling extremely large data volumes: as I've said, your problems will be in the storage of large numbers of records in a table, where sharding that table is a good way of handling the volume... this is a way of distributing the data across several disks or even servers while still providing fast access for your SQL queries - https://www.mysql.com/products/cluster/scalability.html

Comment: @MarkBaker 1st what exactly do you mean with indexing. do you mean to set the primary key? 2nd what do you mean with sharding?

Comment: My previous answer linked to one article about sharding; here's another http://www.slideshare.net/mkindahl/mysql-sharding-tools-and-best-practices-for-horizontal-scaling

Comment: An index is effectively a fast lookup for database searches; you can set an index on `UserId` on your database table, so that a search using `WHERE UserId=12345` will use the index to retrieve the records for that particular user. This isn't the same as PK, though PK Is an index... you can have several indexes on your data tables, not simply one PK

Comment: But if you need to ask questions about indexing, are you sure that you're capable of designing  database to handle these volumes of data?

Comment: yes i guess so @MarkBaker :). okay i am not a professional about database but as far this is the biggest question. the reason for the indexing question was my bad understanding of english so i realised your indexing of some other kind of indexing system.in short, yes i know indexing and how to index :D. but i didn't know anything about sharing so i guess i will study it first.

Comment: You're also going to need an infrastructure that can handle the workload of 20000 database update requests every 2 seconds without being swamped, this isn't the type of thing you can do on goDaddy or other shared hosting.... I'd also recommend farming off all gps position updates to distributed job queues that actually handle the database writes for you to get high throughput; but it does need a serious architect to come up with a design that can handle this kind of workload

Comment: you are absolutely right @MarkBaker. i will use a some kind of a parser for that. i will store all incoming data into txt file with a different server(or farming like you said). then i will use another system that will process these txt files into the database. this will crease some kind of buffer as you mentioned.

Comment: You'll certainly need multiple load balanced servers to handle that many requests per second... appending to text files will still be slow and you'll need to combine from multiple text files (one from each server) when adding the data to the database, which will also be slow reading those text files, and potentially give a lot of contention headaches; that's why I'm suggesting a job queue (RabbitMQ, ZeroMQ, Gearman, etc) instead, which will be a lot faster than using the filesystem

Comment: great thanks @MarkBaker for all you suggestions and recommendations. i will absolutely check them all out. so for now that is my list from you. 1-definitely indexing, 2-sharding, 3-doing queue jobs.

Comment: @MarkBaker would any of your suggestions change if the estimated row for 3 months would be 100million :) ? i realised that i wrote it wrong when i red your post saying "official census" again (again my bad language). really sorry for that. could you please reconsider this?

Comment: The same principles still apply: properly indexed, MySQL should be quite capable of handling large data volume searches, and you still need to be able to handle 10000 logging requests per second

Comment: okay thank you @MarkBaker for all your suggestions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are different views about using many databases vs many tables. the common view is that there isn't any performance disadvantage. i prefered to go with the 1st way (single table). the project is finished and there arent any problems. i dont need to change the table all the time. but my main reason was because it is a little bit more complicated and time-consuming to program many tables style.

1-) on every record; i should directly store all records in a single table? and then call or process them like "... WHERE userId=12345 ...".

besides that here is a link of mysql.com about many tables that could be.
**Disadvantages of Creating Many Tables in the Same Database**
If you have many MyISAM tables in the same database directory, open, close, and create operations are slow. If you execute SELECT statements on many different tables, there is a little overhead when the table cache is full, because for every table that has to be opened, another must be closed. You can reduce this overhead by increasing the number of entries permitted in the table cache.
(http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/creating-many-tables.html)